# Right menu links

Tags: menu

My company website has a main page (header images, our services, testimonials, contacts) and few store pages: an all products page, single product page (only catalog, no buying function).

My headache is what items should I use in the menu.

I have two ideas:

1. *Home // Catalog*
2. Only *Catalog* (instead of Home item use clickable logo)

What can you recommend to do? Is only one item menu good for UX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you know the details of your site better, I will offer some suggestions and insights which could help you with your problem.

BACKGROUND THOUGHTS
 Why does a person come to your website? Write out in percentages what a person wants.  For example, if you are a mechanic shop, people may just be coming to your website to mainly (90% of people) see your address so they can bring there car in. The remaining 10% could just be assessing if you are a good mechanic and the testimonials are important to them.  Based on this analysis, you want to make the things that most people are there for the easiest to do.  Having a menu of 2 items means that these are the 2 most important functions and they are (roughly) of the same importance (50%).

At the end of the day, you want to get the most number of users where they want to go as quickly as possible. 

 I'm going to assume that the goal of your website is to sell products, people coming to it are considering buying, your physical location is not important, that you have both products (more) and services (only a few).

 If these assumptions are roughly correct, I would recommend the home page to consist of..
1) a logo in the upper left for conventions that is clickable to go to the home page
2) a menu on the upper right
3)

```
the menu consisting of 

     'shop' (which could also be named  'products', or 'services','catalog') 

     'testimonials' (which could also be named 'reviews')

     'contact' (which could be named 'contact us') 

      and (maybe) a search icon or bar (if you have enough products)
```

followed by 
4) a visual banner showcasing the products benefits with an actionable item to buy or learn more
5) some testimonials with an option to read more
6) a grid of the items in the catalog possibly with a menu and an option to see more
7) (optionally) a footer with a sitemap

*My recommendations come mainly from just common conventions with a basic understand of your situation, but you know your audience better, and your product offerings.  If you are trying to sell products, don't tuck the only actionable things away behind a menu button.  You will have few sales as most people just load the first page and scroll down on it and leave. I am unclear whether or not you can buy any products from your website based on your description of 'only catalog'. If you can't buy anything then you need to try really hard to direct the user towards an actionable thing like a phone number to place an order.